# Django: How can i set the name field of a newly created record based on autoincrement id?

Tags: django, django-models

I am a newbie in django (and stackoverflow also) but i try to set the name field of a model based of the newly created id of the record. Is there anything like after_save callback where i can check if this is a newly created record and then set the name field based on the new id? Just a note: I want to store this value not just showing it using display_name or somethign like that.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to overwrite the Model's save method like that:

```
class YourModel(model):
    ....
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            update_name=True
        else:
            update_name=False
        super(YourModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        if update_name:
            self.name='whatever %s' %self.id
            super(YourModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Great stuff! Worked like charm! Thanks a lot!